# How can i do reindexing in elasticsearch to migrate from elastic search 1.4 to elasticsearch 5 using Nest api 5

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest, reindex

I am trying to migrate the data from Elasticsearch 1.4 to Elasticsearch 5 using NEST api 5.I was able to migrate one index from ES 1.4 to ES 5 using curl commands but as i am new to elasticsearch i am not aware of how to do the same using Nest api 5 as there is very less examples available to refer for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be possible to do this using the [Reindex from Remote API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html#reindex-from-remote) which is also exposed within NEST as [`ReindexOnServer()`](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/blob/master/src/Nest/Document/Multiple/ReindexOnServer/ElasticClient-ReindexOnServer.cs).

If you need to do any elaborate querying on the source, you may need to use `.Raw()` with a query DSL JSON string, depending on whether the query structure in question has breaking changes between 1.4 and 5.